# What is the difference between Catenate and Flatten?

Tags: functions, matrix, list-manipulation

I am having a hard time understanding the difference between Flatten and Catenate.
Consider the following example code:

```
Catenate[{{a, bc}, {b, cd}}]
Flatten[{{a, bc}, {b, cd}}]
```

Both return this

```
{a,bc,b,cd}
```

I have read the documentation on Catenate but am confused what the different purposes are considering they seem to do the same thing, as well any important subtleties such as time efficiency or scope.

Comment: `{Catenate[{{1, 2}, <|a -> 1, b -> 2|>}],
 Flatten[{{1, 2}, <|a -> 1, b -> 2|>}]}`

Comment: What about the subtle differences and different use cases?

Comment: What might one use Catenate for?

Comment: I was thinking of a real-world example.

Comment: maybe with data or geographic entities.

Comment: `Catenate` combines and sorts multiple lists.  `Flatten` can combine (without sorting) multiple lists but much more besides.

Comment: Why is this question "off-topic"???  It's a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 2):

As is mentioned in the Catenate documentation:

Catenate effectively flattens the first two levels of a high-dimensional array:

So Catenate is a special case of Flatten. And I would guess that Catenate is programmed in terms of Flatten or
its low level representation.

Flatten is a multi purpose function, and its intricacies and uses are not easy to understand. Therefore, there actually are many build-in functions in Mathematica which could be replaced by a corresponding Flatten. I consider those functions as a convenience for the user.